# Addition of COUNT to query causes query to get stuck

Tags: mysql, sql

EDIT: Simplifying it to it's most trivial example:

```
select COUNT(*)
from a_table use index(contract)
left join b_table on a_table.contract = b_table.contract
```

Also, nothing. `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

I have two queries that are nearly identical (`b_table` is a temporary table):

```
select IF (b.contract IS NULL, 1, NULL) c
from a_table a
left join (select contract from b_table) b on a.contract = b.contract
```

This query returns reliably in below .25 seconds. Here is the `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

Here is the same query, only with a `COUNT()` around the `if`:

```
select COUNT(IF (b.contract IS NULL, 1, NULL)) c
from a_table a
left join (select contract from b_table) b on a.contract = b.contract
```

This one shows 'sending data' and at least after several minutes, seems to hang and I get nothing. Here is the `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

(Note that `d` == `a_table a` and `eric_tmp` == `b_table`. Hopefully not too confusing.)

This is the original query that caused the kerfuffle, with the above an attempt to rewrite it:

```
select count(*) from a_table a
where not exists (select 1 from b_table b where a.contract = b.contract)
```

Which of course also hung. What the heck is going on here? I've tried adding and using a non-unique index, but it also doesn't seem to help. I don't understand why a `COUNT` would cause a problem here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry about that.

Comment: Change count for sum:  SUM(IF (b.contract IS NULL, 1, 0)) c and test

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM engine?

Comment: @ImreL - They are both InnoDB.

Comment: what are the datatypes of field `contract` on both tables?

Comment: @ImreL - They are both `varchar(27)`. I would also add I copied the temp table and setup the query between the two temps, no problem. I also have an `a_table` copy (of a different vintage) and using only those two, no problem. It's got to be the index.

Comment: Since the one one without `count` returns result fast, what if you wrap it as subquery in `select count(*) from (...)`?

Comment: @ImreL - Gordon Linoff makes a valid point that the `LIMIT` could be contributing to that performance (it's only returning the first 30 of tens of thousands). I had another scenario where adding `b_table.contract IS NULL` also caused it to stick, whereas without it the `COUNT` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably consider the first query done when it returns the first row, rather than the last row.  The second query needs to go through all the data, before it can return anything.

Subqueries (which MySQL calls "derived tables") affect performance.  Negatively.

Your `not exists` query is quite reasonable:

```
select count(*)
from a_table a
where not exists (select 1 from b_table b where a.contract = b.contract);
```

For performance, you want an index on `b_table(contract)`.  This will probably fix your performance problem, unless the tables are really big.

Comment: There is an index on `b_table.contract`. I would agree that query looks perfectly fine, yet it sticks and never returns anything (at least as long as I'm willing to wait, ~5m). Also, we're talking 35-45k rows in each. not large.

Comment: @JaredFarrish . . . With an index, this query should finish in seconds or tens of seconds.  Are you sure you have an index on table b where `contract` is the first key in the index?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in the explain.

Comment: @JaredFarrish . . . You should fix your query so the table names in the explain match the table names in the query.